# Firebase security rules insufficient permissions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have the owner role in my firebase project and I am trying to secure my Firestore Database. I want my collections to be secured by default and only accessible if I make a rule for it. I created my database in production mode. However, for some reason even if I specify  a rule that allows me to access a collection I receive a `Missing or insufficient permissions` error

For example when I register a user I also want to create my own user collection.
registering the user works but creating my collection does not work.

***register user query (works and adds a user to firebase authentication)***

```
register(value) : Promise<any> {
    return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(value.email, value.password)
        .then(res => {
            resolve(res);
        }, err => {
            console.log(err)
            reject(err);
            })
    
    });
}
```

***Create User collection query (CreateCurrentUserCollection does not work)***

```
public async getCurrentUser() : Promise<any> 
    {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            let user = this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user){
                if (user) {
                    resolve(user);
                } else {
                    reject('No user logged in');
                }
            });
        });
    }   

public CreateCurrentUserCollection(): void
{
  this.authService.getCurrentUser().then(res => {
        this.firestore.collection<User>("usersBackup")
            .add({
                uid: res.uid,
                username: res.email
            })
  });
}
```

***Firebase rules***

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      
       match /users {
        allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2221, 7, 20);
       }
       
       match /usersBackup {
        allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2221, 7, 20);
       }
  }
}
```

if I add the following rule for example

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
```

it does work. However then none of my other security rules work, where I want to prevent certain users from accessing certain documents. What am I missing or doing wrong? Please let me know if you need more information thank you in advance.

**Update**

As noted by Dharmaraj in his answer security rules must point to documents and not collection. This fixes my issue with one of my collection. However I also have a projects collection with an array field called projectMembers. I only want users with a uid inside the projectMembers array to have access to a project document. For some reason It is always giving me `Missing or insufficient permissions` error, even if the projects collection is empty.

***query***

```
    public getProjectsOfUser(userUid: string) : Observable<IProject[]> {
        return this.firestore.collection<IProject>("projects", ref => 
            ref.where("projectMembers", "array-contains", userUid))
           .valueChanges({ idField: 'id'});
}
```

***Firebase Rules***

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      
       match /users/{userID} {
        allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == userID
       }
       
       match /usersBackup/{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2221, 7, 20);
       }
        
      match /projects/{projectId} {
        allow read, write: if 
            isProjectMember(projectId, request.auth.uid);
      }
      
      //functions
    function isSignedIn()
    {
        return request.auth != null;
    }
    
    function isProjectMember(projectId, userId) {
    return userId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId)).data.projectMembers;
    }
    
  }
}
```

***Database Structure***
[image]

***Firebase Playground***
[image]

***JWT token send to Firebase by Angular***
[image]

Comment: Add /{userId} or /{DocId} on to these to grant read/write on specific docs.  Please check out our security guide. https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Comment: @Kato How do I grant read/read to some documents of a collection but not others? I have updated my question if you could please take a look

Comment: @Kato as you can see the user_id in the jwt send by angular matches the uid in my database. Somehow the security rule works in the firebase playground. Why does my angular query not work?

Comment: Hello, please try if `resource.data.projectMembers` work as I've posted in the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior#:%7E:text=All%20match%20statements%20should%20point%20to%20documents%2C%20not%20collections.),

> All match statements should point to documents, not collections. A match statement can point to a specific document, as in match /cities/SF or use wildcards to point to any document in the specified path, as in match /cities/{city}.

If you want users to edit their own document only you should try:

```
match /users/{userID} {
  allow read, write: request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userID;
}
```

If not, then you can try adding a [recursive wildcard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) so the rule will be applied for all the documents in that collection:

```
match /users/{document=**} {
  allow read, write: request.time < timestamp.date(2221, 7, 20);
}
```

**Do note that anyone can write to any document if you use the recursive wildcard.**

**Update:**
To check if an UID exists in the array.

```
allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid in resource.data.projectMembers
```

Comment: Use the second, more specific example when possible and write rules for each subcollection. Avoid wildcards in almost all cases. As the OP discovered, this often overrides more specific rules in unexpected ways and creates security holes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Kato . Edited the answer to emphasize on that.

Comment: Thank you Dharmaraj, pointing the security rule to a document instead of collection helped in this case. However I'm running into a similar issue when I write a security rule for securing data based on the users UID. I've updated my question if you could please take a look

Comment: @Jiren check the updated answer. If the doesn't work for you then please share screenshots of your db structure and any error that you get from the rules.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Your version of isProjectMember does not work. It is missing the $(database) variable as parameter, but even if I add it, it does not work. The rule it self does not give me any other errors other than the insufficient permissions error. I've updated my question providing my database structure. If you could please take a look.

Comment: @Jiren please add my function inside of `/databases/{database}/documents { ... }`

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've added the function inside /databases/{database}/documents { ... }, but I am still getting the error. I've updated my question to reflect what I have done

Comment: @Jiren please try those rules in the Firestore Security rules emulator in the console and share a screenshot :D

Comment: I've tried the rules playground. I don't know if that's what you meant. I wouldn't know how to use the firebase console. The playground is not giving me any useful information. I've added a screenshot to my question

Comment: @Jiren yes I mean playground. Please type the path only as `/projects/<projectID>` and then try. Also moving this convo to a discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234469/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-jiren).